# Skipping an $index() in a Knockout Observable Array

Tags: knockout.js

I have a table that is displaying some information from a Knockout `observableArray`, and I use a data-binding of `text: $index() + 1` to display each item's position in the array. Now, I'd like to be able to skip an item's position and just make it blank if a value for the item is `true`. So the end result would be a normal 1 to `x` index being displayed, but for every item that had a certain value set to `true` then no index would be displayed and the index count would pick up after that item as if that item was not included in the index count at all.

I've made a [simple jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/3Ww4k/1/) to illustrate the problem.

Any ideas on the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional operator in `td` data binding, and display or empty string or index:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: isresting ? '' : $index() + 1"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>  
        <td data-bind="text: isresting"></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ww4k/2/)

**Update**

I've update my implementation and have added a function which correct calculating index:

Html:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $parent.getIndexForMan($data)"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>  
        <td data-bind="text: isresting"></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray();
    self.getIndexForMan = function(man) {
        if (man.isresting) {
            return null;
        }        
        var index = 1;
        var rawPeople = self.people();
        for (var i = 0; i < rawPeople.length; i++) {
            if (rawPeople[i] == man) {
                break;
            }
            if (!rawPeople[i].isresting) {
                index++;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
};

var model = new ViewModel();
model.people(data);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ww4k/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a child ViewModel, where I toggle the index's visibility

http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/wx2se/2/

```
<table data-bind="foreach: PeopleMap">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: PersonIndex, visible: !IsResting()"></span>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: IsResting"></td>
    </tr>
</table>


var ViewModel = function (theData) {
    var _self = this;
    var personCount = 0;
    _self.PeopleMap = ko.observableArray(
    ko.utils.arrayMap(theData, function (item) {
        if(!item.isresting){
            personCount++;
        }
        return new PeopleViewModel(item, personCount);
    }));
};

var PeopleViewModel = function (data, personCount) {
    var _self = this;
    _self.Name = ko.observable(data.name);
    _self.IsResting = ko.observable(data.isresting);
    _self.PersonIndex = ko.observable(personCount);
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
```